# Lua Error: "Gnuplot terminal is not set"

Tags: lua, gnuplot, torch

In LuaJIT or in the Torch REPL, I run the commands
    
    `require 'gnuplot'
    gnuplot.figure()`

and I get the error "Gnuplot terminal is not set".

I tried using gnuplot.setterm() with some guesses such as 'x11' and 'qt' as arguments, but get the error "gnuplot does not seem to have this term". Is there somewhere I can get a list of terminal emulators/graphics backends available to gnuplot? Or alternatively, are these errors indicative of some other problem?

Comment: What are you doing? What code/script do you refer to?

Comment: Does the [gnuplot documentation for `set terminal`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-27100043.62) or the [list of terminal types](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-346000III) help?

Comment: Unfortunately not; the lua gnuplot library's set term function does give the functionality of the 'set terminal' command from the documentation you provided, but when I try to set the terminal to options from the list of terminals, I get a 'terminal not found' error.

Comment: I'll have to come back and troubleshoot this when I'm more experienced with Lua. I'll post the solution at then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you get this error if you don't have the [Gnuplot executable](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html) installed.

I didn't check for this problem before because gnuplot.lua (v. 5.1) has an error check for the case of that executable being unavailable - on line 145 - but for some reason it failed to catch the problem.

Comment: This error can also happen if you're using x11 but don't have gnuplot-x11 installed. The fix is to run sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11. Found this solution [here](http://lordamit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/solution-gnuplot-in-ubuntu-terminal.html).