# Gnu plot error with lua/torch (OS X)

Tags: macos, lua, gnuplot, torch

I want to run some code in torch that requires the gnuplot lib however I get the following error;

```
/Users/mattsmith/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:127: Gnuplot terminal is not set
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:127: in function 'getfigure'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:808: in function 'figure'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:288: in function 'getCurrentPlot'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:308: in function 'writeToCurrent'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:836: in function 'gnulplot'
    ...attsmith/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/gnuplot/gnuplot.lua:976: in function 'plot'
    practical3.lua:217: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...mith/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0104467190
```

I read here [Lua Error: "Gnuplot terminal is not set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882271/lua-error-gnuplot-terminal-is-not-set) that I require the gnu plot executable installed. So I downloaded this and followed the website instructions here http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html and then I get this error;

```
In file included from ./term.h:414:
../term/lua.trm:113:10: fatal error: 'lua.h' file not found
#include <lua.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [term.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Not too sure if I am going about this the correct way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The [install options used in the official dependency script](https://github.com/torch/ezinstall/blob/8e9067e5f6805453f9ba302a44ba9bfab8e02694/install-deps#L79-L80) might be what you need in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Find wherever lua.h is located. For me it was in: `/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.5_1/include/lua`

Then, open lua.trm inside the gnuplot installation files, find `#include lua.h` and replace it with `path/lua.h`. In my case: `/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.5_1/include/lua/lua.h`

You will notice that there are other "includes" that will throw the same error as the one with lua.h. There are all on the same path. Therefore, modify the includes the in the same manner.